# How to split one column into 2 columns in MySQL for hive table?

Tags: sql, mysql, hive

I want to split the name column into 2 columns where there are many hiphens(-) in the name but I want to split from the last hiphen(-) in MySQL in hive db.

for example check the check the below table

| name | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a-b-c-d_b | 23 | M |
| d-e-f-g_e | 44 | F |

I want the output to be like splitting the name column with only last (-)

So the output table should be like the one below

| name | new_name | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a-b-c-d_b | d_b | 23 | M |
| d-e-f-g_e | g_e | 44 | F |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this in MySql

```
SELECT name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '-', -1) AS new_name, age, gender FROM your_table;
```